# socket.io only working in main server file, not in route files

Tags: node.js, sockets

*Version 2 of post*

Okay, first the file structure:

```
app
|___app.js
|___models/
    |_user.js
|___routes/
    |___admin.js
|___public/
    |___js/
        |___script.js
```

**app.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, function (err){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Server is running");
});
```

**script.js**:

```
var socket = io();

//Next, this tells the browser that is has connected to the socket.io server
socket.on('connect', function() {
   console.log('Connected to socket.io server!');
});

socket.on('message', function(message){
    console.log('New message: ');
    console.log(message.text);
});

var $newUsername = $('#Username');

$newUsername.on('blur', function(event){
    socket.emit('message', {
        text: $newUsername.val()
    });
});
```

So on a registration page, if a user enters a 'username' already in the database, it will console.log 'This user already exists'. At least, that's the idea.

There is still sockets.io code I need to add on the server side. I am trying to put it here:

**admin.js**:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var User = require('../models/user');

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('User connected via socket.io!');

    socket.on('message', function(message) {

Username.findOne({username: message.text}, function (err, existingUsername) {
    if (existingUsername) {
        console.log('This user already exists: ' + message.text);
    }
    });
});
});
```

So, as this stands, the sockets.io code in admin.js won't work because it can't access the **io** function. I would like to know how I can fix this.

To add to this: The sockets.io code I have in the **admin.js** file will work fine if I placed it in my **app.js** file.

Comment: Why doesn't it work in your other files?  socket.io doesn't care one bit what route the page is.  If you want a username to be available in all your files, then set it into a cookie that can be obtained in either client pages or on the server anytime you need it.

Comment: when you say route file. which route file/ the home page or registration form page. ?

Comment: are you concerned that you don't want to permanently listen on this port just for a use name validation? so you want to kick start listening from route file which render registration page?

Comment: So, I figured out a solution to my problem. I made the first 2 variables, http and io, global by removing the 'var' in front of them. Now my sockets.io code works fine in my route files. I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to pass the `io` instance to any module that needs it when that module is first loaded.  This is called the "push" method of sharing as you share by pushing data from one module to another by passing it in the constructor function of the other module.

There is also a "pull" module where one module asks some other module for some shared data by calling a method in that module.

Here's how you could implement the "push" model:

In your admin.js file, you define a constructor function that you call and pass the `io` instance to when you load it:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
var io;

// define constructor function that receives the io instance so the rest
// of the module can use it
module.exports = function(ioInstance) {
    io = ioInstance;
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log('User connected via socket.io!');

        socket.on('message', function(message) {

            Username.findOne({
                username: message.text
            }, function(err, existingUsername) {
                if (existingUsername) {
                    console.log('This user already exists: ' + message.text);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Then, in your app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, function (err){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Server is running");
});

// when you load the admin.js file, you pass it the io instance
require('./routes/admin.js')(io);
```

Comment: Thanks for all that... but it is producing an error. The error is produced when adding '(io)' after 'require('./routes/admin.js')'. This is the error: ...\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:140
  var search = 1 + req.url.indexOf('?');
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Comment: @MonkeyOnARock - That error doesn't appear to be coming from any of edits I've suggested.  You are apparently doing something else wrong that is not in the code you show in your question.  Not much we can do without seeing the code.

Comment: Okay, I had some syntax error elsewhere on the page. But it works now! Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

**Below are 2 answers. While both answers will technically work, it is advised that you do not use either of them. Use the answer provided above.**

---

**Answer 2**

So my route files all have this:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
```

Now, in any of the route files where I need sockets.io I did this:

```
var http = require('http').Server(router);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

And this got my sockets.io code working.

---

**Answer 1**

So to get sockets.io code working in my route files, I simply removed 'var' in front of my http and io variables.

I changed:

```
//Socket io config
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

to this:

```
//Socket io config
http = require('http').Server(app);
io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Now my sockets.io code in my route files work fine.

Comment: This is likely a horrible solution.  If you have multiple modules (something you do NOT disclose in your question), then the proper way to share variables between modules is to pass them in the module constructor when you load the modules, NOT to make variables into accidental globals.

Comment: I don't see any change.

Comment: Forgot to hit send. It's there now.

Comment: This tries to start a new http server and socket.io server in every route file.  I don't see how this could possible be correct.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual route files you have and how you are loading them from your main app so we can explain to you how to pass the `io` instance to your route files properly.